# Get the value of select jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<select id="my-select">
<option value="1">This is one</option>
<option value="2" selected>This is two</option>
...
</select>
```

Is there a way to get the text value of the selected option?

```
$('#my-select').val();
```

gives me 2, i want to get This is Two instead.

How?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you want is

1. Get the selector for finding the selected option in the select box
2. Use [**`.text()`**](http://api.jquery.com/text/) on the selector.

   ```
   $('#my-select option:selected').text();
   ```

See a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/UxYpS/)